# Center property in UIView seems to cause bug

Tags: ios, uiview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to centre the `UIImageView` inside my custom `UICollectionViewCell`. But when I am trying the following code:

```
self.imageView.center = self.center;
```

my imageView doesn't appear inside cell at all. But if I do:

```
self.imageView.center = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2);
```

then everything is positioned as intended.
Is it some sort of bug, or i miss something here?

Comment: It is not bug. It is how it should work. in first line you are trying to set canter of cell (with reference to table) to image view. Which is not same ass second line.

Comment: log self.cemter and CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2). You will get that both are different.